# Spring Boot: Cors policy missing 'access-control-allow-origin'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, axios

Error: I get the following in Firefox: Foreign Site Query Blocked: The same origin policy does not allow reading of the remote resource http: // localhost: 8080 / api / v1 / post /. (Cause: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' CORS header does not exist)

I have spent several hours to allow CORS communication with my Spring Boot server in order to make my REACT UI communicate with the server. There are lot of similarly phrased questions on Stack Overflow, but non of the suggested solutions have solved my problem...

Spring Boot suggests different solutions on https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/. One local solution is using annotations. A global solution can be obtained with a config file.

I have tried annotating the controller with `@CrossOrigin` as seen in my code below:

```
package com.example.Blogging.api;

import com.example.Blogging.model.Post;
import com.example.Blogging.service.PostService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;


@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("api/v1/post")
@RestController
public class PostController {

    private final PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    public PostController(PostService postService) {
        this.postService = postService;
    }


    @PostMapping
    public void addPost(@RequestBody Post post){
        postService.addPost(post);

    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Post> getAllPosts(){
        return postService.getAllPosts();

    }

    @GetMapping(path = "{id}")
    public Optional<Post> getPostById(@PathVariable("id") UUID id){
        return postService.getPostById(id);

    }

    @PutMapping(path="{id}")
    public void updatePostById(@PathVariable("id") UUID id, @RequestBody Post post){
        postService.updatePost(id,post);
    }


    @DeleteMapping(path="{id}")
    public void deletePostById(@PathVariable("id") UUID id){
        postService.deletePost(id);
    }


}
```

This did not work.. I have also tried annotating on each method instead of the whole controller class.

Furthermore I have tried to make a config file:

```
package com.example.Blogging.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Nothing really seems to work. The console in my browser keeps saying 'access-control-allow-origin' is missing in the response header..

For reference, I will also put my pom.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Blogging</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Blogging</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->



        <!-- SPRING BOOT STARTER SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Anyone who can suggest a solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you getting this error for all HTTP methods?

Comment: Just a comment, I see in your `PostController` in your annotation `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` port 3000 instead in your text you mention port 8080. Could it be that you have a typo in ports and that's the reason for not working?

Comment: I guess that 3000 is where the Frontend App is running and 8080 where the Backend service is. But I might be assuming this in the wrong way. Can you confirm this @WillGates?

Comment: I am getting it for all HTTP methods yes. Also I tried @CrossOrigin(origins = "*"), which should have worked for any port

Comment: What happens if you omit the @CrossOrigin and just have the webconfig?

Comment: I just noticed, you use spring security. Can you share your websecurity config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed, you have Spring Security in your dependencies.
You might missed to enable CORS in your WebSecurityConfig.

Eg. something like this:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and()...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I agree this seems likely to be the issue. For documentation reference on this see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors

Comment: Ahh yes, that's probably it. I'm currently not on home, but when I try it, and if it works, I will mark this as the solution! Thank you very much for your help :) !